# How to prevent mold growth on moss ( kept in a closed jar )?

Tags: mold, moss, humidity

The moss is kept in a closed, humid environment, and white mold is taking over in some parts. Any advise on how to prevent the mold from competing and overtaking the moss?

When I look for answers on the web I usually find information on how to get rid of both the mold and the moss together.

I previously posted a [general question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1726/), but I am still trying to find an answer to this more specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem. Some of my covered moss tanks grow white mold; the uncovered ones rarely do. Things you can do:

- Pull the mold out and throw it away (I use 12" long tweezers).
- Use spring tails (a type of bug that will live in the ground and eat the mold at night).
- If possible use a small PC fan to get air movement.
- Keep an organism that eats the mold.

In one of my smaller tanks I have a red clawed crab and he eats the mold. He actually prefers it over his food. From what I have read online though the mold will go away after a while - it's all part of the tank or jar establishing itself. I still don't know the name of this mold or if there are treatments for it but this is what I've learned and most of it is from trying things and seeing what works.

Answer (score 4):

I find that I can grow moss in diffuse or strong interior sunlight as long as it is continuously moist.   A closed jar is not an easy place to grow moss as you have found.  Could you just open up the top for a few hours every day?